# Dynamic sliding div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery, so any help is appreciated.

I am "sort of" trying to reproduce this:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HoverSlideEffect/

However, I want to use DIV tags with web content in them vs images. I'm working on a website for my girlfriends salon, so I want the content to change when a person chooses Services>>Contact>>Team... etc.

I also don't want the box to slide when the mouse is over. I only want to trigger the change when a button is clicked.

I sorta tried to mess with this code, but it's a little complex for me at my current state. I wrote my own code that is sort of working, but here's my problem:

If I open the page and choose the first button, everything is fine. Because I basically have the div sliding out and another one sliding back in its place; however, if I went form button 1 to button 2, it doesn't work. I'm not sure how to make the div tags "generic" so no matter what content is in the current box, the new content will replace it.

I understand "this" but not sure how to apply it. I did code school, but that only gave me a basic understanding.

I copied the code, but it's not working on jsfiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/xrXLg/

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#contact").css({opacity: "0", width: "0", left: "0"});

$(".run").click(function(){
    $("#services").animate({opacity: "1", width: "450"}, 400);
    $("#contact").animate({opacity: "1", width: "600"}, 400);
});
```

});

Comment: add jsfiddle link to your attempts please

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to do using jQuery. Here is an example with one container. However, you can add as many as you wish. They will be working simultaneously. Sliding will start on mouse click.

HTML Part:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slide active" style="background:red;">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background:yellow;">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background:green;">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="slide" style="background:blue;">Slide 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS Part:

```
.container {position:relative; width: 400px; height: 200px;}
.slide {position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; line-height:200px; text-align:center; display:none;}
.slide.active {display:block;}
```

JS Part:

```
jQuery('.container').bind('click', function(){
    var container = jQuery(this), slides = container.children('.slide');
    var current = container.children('.slide.active');
    var currentID = slides.index(current);
    var nextID = currentID < slides.length - 1 ? currentID + 1 : 0;
    var next = jQuery(slides[nextID]);
    if (jQuery('.container .active').length == 2) return;
    next.addClass('active');
    next.css('opacity', 0);
    current.animate({
        left: -container.width(),
        opacity: 0
    }, 1000, function(){
        current.removeClass('active');
        current.css({left: 0, opacity: 1});
    });
    next.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
});
```

Here is the example on jsfiddle.net - http://jsfiddle.net/qe4Tt/

Comment: Nico, thanks.. but will this work for what I'm trying to do? I basically want the content in the boxes to change to from 1 page to another like a transformer. I'm using this idea as the different pages of the website. So I need them to coordinate when I click the button. I'm not sure, but your example appears like it's going in sequence. I need, for example, 6 div tags to change 5 different ways. But I need them to change to the proper page (IE Services or Contact us) when the button is clicked no matter what page is already loaded. I'm having trouble explaining this, so I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. The jQuery library was not included your jsFiddle. I added that now. Here's the link to the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xrXLg/2/. I am adding your code here as I cannot submit an answer with a jsFiddle link in it unless I also include a code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact").css({opacity: "0", width: "0", left: "0"});
    $(".run").click(function(){
        $("#services").animate({opacity: "1", width: "450"}, 400);
        $("#contact").animate({opacity: "1", width: "600"}, 400);
    });
});
```